# Правильно ли составлено условие? (SQL, PHP)

Tags: php, sql

Код рабочий, просто для себя хочу узнать правильно ли составил условия?
  Суть кода такая, Сменить значение count на 4, при условии что запись была сделана (timestamp) 7 дней назад и значение count=2 или count=3

```
$s = 7; 
$close = (time()-86400*$s); 
$db->Query(
   "UPDATE `table` 
    SET `count`='4' 
    WHERE `timestamp` > 0 AND 
    `timestamp` < '".$close."'  
    AND (`count`='2' OR `count`='3')" 
);
```

Comment: Ну так запускайте ваш код и проверяйте что он сделает (или не сделает :С )

Comment: Если у Вас в `timestamp` хранится цифра, которую Вы получали через `time()` во время записи, то в принципе условие нормальное. *86400х7=7(суток) в секундах* . `time()` - возвращает количество секунд, прошедших с начала Эпохи до текущего времени. Вроде бы все похоже на правду

Comment: Понятно, спасибо за ответ)

Comment: @AndreiAndrei, написал ответ и расписал немного более детально

Comment: Лучше в БД хранить поле типа datetime и в запросе писать что то типа `timestamp<now()-interval $s day` А если в секундах хранить и дальше то можно что то вроде `timestamp<unix_timestamp(now()-interval $s day)`

Comment: Я в принципе думал о таком варианте, но остановился на своем)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рассмотрим Ваш код более детально.

```
$s = 7; // 7 дней
$close = (time()-86400*$s); // в сутках 86400 секунд
$db->Query(
   "UPDATE `table` // обновить таблицу
    SET `count`='4' // установить count=4
    WHERE `timestamp` > 0 AND // у которых timestamp положительно
    `timestamp` < '".$close."'  // у которых timestamp ранее семи дней назад 
    AND (`count`='2' OR `count`='3')" // у которых count = 2 или 3
);
```

- В одних сутках 86400 секунд.
- В семи сутках 7*86400 секунд.
- [`time()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.time.php) - возвращает количество секунд, прошедших с начала Эпохи до текущего времени.
- Если от [`time()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.time.php) вычесть количество секунд семи суток - получим день равный семи дням назад - в секундах конечно же

Если у Вас в timestamp хранится цифра, которую Вы получали через [`time()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.time.php) во время записи, то в принципе условие нормальное. Вроде бы все похоже на правду.

Comment: Спасибо за детальный ответ), да время timestamp получено через  time().